# How can I get this code to pass when the user is not logged in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this form:

```
<%= form_for current_user.relationships.build(:followed_id => @profile.user.id) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.hidden_field :followed_id %></div>
  <div class="follow_button"><%= f.submit "Follow" %></div>
<% end %>
```

and since it uses `current_user` it throws an error when the user is not logged in. I want a non-logged in user to be able to see the button, but for it to fail:

`before_filter :authenticate`

when clicked. How should I change the form code? Seems like I may need to move the relationship.build call to the controller? Or how would I make the button call the `authenticate` method in my application controller?

Comment: You want to give users a form to fill out so they can then fail, be forced to log in, and lose the data they entered? Seems like a pretty bad UX.

Comment: It's not a full form. It's just a button for following. I want users to see the features that are available after logging in...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think its good practise to call User.new as proposed before. You can always differentiate in your view:

```
<% if current_user %>
  Form goes here
<% else %>
  <div class="follow_button">Log in to follow</div>
<% end %>
```

(or make a second button that leads to sign-in)

Answer (score 0):

You could always add a generic "logged out" user to the system, default to that when no session is present, and then check for that user when the click is handled.  That'd give you the kind of flexibility you want without mucking up your model.

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
<% user = current_user || User.new %>

    <%= form_for user.relationships.build(:followed_id => @profile.user.id) do |f| >  <div>
      <%= f.hidden_field :followed_id %></div>   <div class="follow_button">
      <%= f.submit "Follow" %>
    </div>
     <% end %>
```

I have pretty much the same relations in my app and it seems to work:

```
User.new.friendships.build(:friend_id => 4) # =>
<Friendship id: nil, user_id: 0, friend_id: 4, approved: false, canceled: false, marked_as_deleted: false, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```